# Apigility Admin UI Not Opening

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, zend-framework3

so my apigility admin area was working just fine before they updated it to ZF3.

No after composer update, I am getting this when I try to open /apigility/ui

[image: /apigility/ui page]

Does anyone know what might be the problem and how can we resolve this issue ?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Check your web server logs to see if there are any errors reported, make sure error reporting is turned on, maybe a comparison of your composer.json (or lock file) before problems and after. All of those should help drill down where the problem lies.

Comment: I was facing same issue then i included public in url like this http://example.com/public/apigility/ui.. Now its working

Answer (score 2):

**The Issue is:**
In the error logs you'll find that css and js data is not loaded. As the rwoverdijk/assetmanager is removed since apigility Admin 1.5 some files are not loaded anymore.

**Solution:**
Follow part 2. of the Upgrade from https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin#initial-upgrade-to-15

I also tried part 1 what was also working because now the rwoverdijk/assetmanager is now on 1.7.1 (but i do not know if the incompatibility is solved with this version so i did it with the zfcampus/zf-asset-manager). I'm still on ZF2 but the issue is the same.

Install zf-asset-manager. This is a Composer plugin, and operates when installing or uninstalling a package. If you add this, you will need to follow these steps:

```
composer require --dev zfcampus/zf-asset-manager

rm -Rf ./vendor

composer install
```

The additional steps are necessary in order for the plugin to pick up on the assets from the other components and copy them to the public folder. After installation you ll find a folder apigility-ui in you

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me when I reused the same code for a new repository on my local development environment having set the base_path value on
*./module/Application/config/module.config.php*.

> 'view_manager' => [
>           'base_path' => 'https://subdomain1.example.com',..]

I solved it by deleting the base_path config value.

The view cannot be rendered fully as the wrong html base is injected to the rendered view. In my case the html base looked like

`<base href="http://subdomain2.example.com.devhttps://subdomain1.example.com/">`

Instead of

```
<base href="http://subdomain2.example.com.dev">
```